# Not seeing navigation barButton items in my tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview

I created a UITableViewController in my main.storyboard, then linked it up with the class called MainMenu. In the class, I manually added  UIBarButtonItems to add friends and to log out, but I don't see anything. All I see is a blank table view with the gray lines.

```
 class MainMenu: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))

    let image = UIImage(named: "add_friend_image")


    let menuButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    menuButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 20, height: 20)
    menuButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleFriend), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside) 

    let menuBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menuButton)
    let currWidth = menuBarItem.customView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24)
    currWidth?.isActive = true
    let currHeight = menuBarItem.customView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24)
    currHeight?.isActive = true;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menuBarItem



}
```

Comment: Does your table view controller sit inside a UINavigationController?

Comment: No. Do I add that in code or in storyboard?

Comment: You can add it in the storyboard. With the table view controller selected you have to embed it in navigation controller. I think that option is under the *editor* menu but not completely sure.

Comment: It's simple to fix. Just add a UINavigationController

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Storyboard and add your `TableViewController` i.e `MainMenu`
2. Embed the `MainMenu` controller in `Navigation Controller`
3. Set the navigation controller as the initial view controller
4. Then in `viewDidLoad` of `MainMenu` class add your code to set the navigation bar button items

   ```
   class MainMenu: UITableViewController {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))

           let image = UIImage(named: "add_friend_image")


           let menuButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
           menuButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 20, height: 20)
           menuButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
           menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleFriend), for: .touchUpInside)

           let menuBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menuButton)
           let currWidth = menuBarItem.customView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24)
           currWidth?.isActive = true
           let currHeight = menuBarItem.customView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24)
           currHeight?.isActive = true;
           self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menuBarItem
       }

       @objc func handleLogout() {

       }

       @objc func handleFriend() {

       }
   }
   ```

**Steps are added for Storyboard file,**

[image: Image 1][image: Image 2][image: Image 3]

**The output is,**

[image: output]